# JQuery Accordion active on document load instead of on click despite having active false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the JQuery accordion that contains nested accordions that worked fine when I had them purely in HTML. But in my case, I have to load the nested accordions in JQuery and that prevents the accordion from only being activated when clicked. The accordion is already open when the page loads. I also tried putting the accordion last in the JS and it still did not work. Code snippet:

HTML/ERB:

```
<% @year.each do |y| %> 
<div class="accordion" id="years">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header year"><a href="#"><%= y.date %></a></h3>
</div>
<% end %>
```

JS:

```
var months = [];
var loadURL = "stats/show";

$("div.accordion").accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         active: false,
         autoHeight: true,
         event: "click"
});  


$.getJSON(loadURL, function(data){
  //parse data and place in empty arrays
  for(var key in data.month){
     months.push(data.month[key]);
  }

  //give each year tab an index number
  $('h3.year').each(function(index){
      $(this).attr('id', 'ui-accordion-years-header-' + index);
  })

  for(var i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
    //create and append month container to each year tab
    $("#ui-accordion-years-header-" + i).after("<div id='months" + i + "' class='months accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-content ui-widget-content'></div>");  


    for (var j = 0; j < months[i].length; j++){
        //parse each month of the year and place month tabs in month container
        var accordion_month = '<h3 class= "ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="months_tab' + j + '" aria-controls="ui-accordion-1-panel-0" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"><a href="#" name=' + months[i][j] + '>' +  months[i][j] + '</a></h3>';


        $("#months" + i).append(accordion_month);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting accordion inside `getJSON` after all statements in that function?

Comment: That worked. Last line _inside_ the getJSON statement. Thank you.

Comment: I shall make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put accordian inside `$.getJSON()`.

What you have done is added accordian before getting data.

So accordion is empty.

Then, you try to get data...

So accordion does not make it without the data.

So putting `accordion` inside `$.getJSON` after all statements makes all available for accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the accordion **after** you successfully get the json and append all the elements inside.

Comment: I had tried that. I put the accordion at the last line and it still didn't work.

Comment: Then your HTML is malformed. Post a jsfiddle or demo of it in action.